# How can I buy a laptop/desktop to ensure compatibility with Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Pretty much every laptop and desktop I look at comes with Windows 10. I had a bad experience trying to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I've given up that idea. I had deactivated secure boot, but it didn't work out. I had to abandon Ubuntu and do a full re-installation of Windows 10. It was a Surface Book...

Now I'd like to get a computer just for Ubuntu, but I know that there are some issues with setting up Ubuntu to replace Windows 10, and there can be hardware issues too. The issue is so fraught with angst that it would almost drive me to stick with Windows, even though I'm drawn to Linux, particularly Ubuntu.

So, I wanted to ask how I should go about making sure the computer I buy will be OK with Ubuntu in terms of drivers, hardware, etc... and how can I be sure that the installation will go well?

I am a real beginner vis-à-vis Linux; I'm fairly confident with using Windows 10 for daily things and doing the basic tasks.

Comment: This appears to be within the scope of a ["constructive subjective question"](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Do you want something very new and high-end? If not, waiting till someone else has done it first *is* a viable option.

Comment: Windows 10 these days has quite a robust Linux subsystem capability (WSL). Is that something you're open to? See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 6):

There are a range of brands that sell laptops pre-installed with Ubuntu and with manufacturer support. As of March 2020, there are a few articles around on [where to go](https://itsfoss.com/get-linux-laptops/).

Other than that, the Lenovo ThinkPad T series is [famous for Linux compatibility](https://linuxhint.com/linux_lenovo_thinkpad/). I have a ThinkPad T460 and it's been absolutely great.

Lenovo even keep a public [list of models that support linux](https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/pd031426).

Comment: Yes I looked at the Thinkpads, however I heard that AMD can be problematic?

Comment: I don't know who you are listening to - I'm writing this on an AMD-powered laptop, VPN'd through an AMD-powered server. AMD works just as well as Intel. New hardware by any manufacturer has problems when folks put a years-old OS onto it.

Comment: Would the latest Lenovo Thinkpad E595 AMD be a good choice? Having said that, I'm torn between that and buying a desktop.

Comment: AMD vs Intel is a non-issue. The Thinkpad 'T' series have the best reputation for running Linux. Have you had a look at Lenovo's [official list of hardware that supports Linux](https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/pd031426)?

Comment: Thanks, but the Thinkpad E595 is not on that list.

Comment: Then, unless someone can personally attest to having run Linux on it with no issues, I'd stay away from it.

Comment: Are the Tiny computers from Lenovo a good option? At least one of them is included on the compatibility chart, ThinkCentre M630e Tiny and also ThinkCentre M920 and M630e.

Comment: I am using Thinkpad P51 with great success. pretty much all the hardware works (I didn't bother with gimmicks like the fingerprint reader)

Comment: I'm running an HP G6 Pavillion with an AMD A6-9220, bought with no OS. The only difficulty I had was that the wifi was not handled by the stock kernel installed with Mint, and had to upgrade to the latest kernel.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this list of [Ubuntu certified hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?query=&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&level=&release=18.04%20LTS&vendors=Acer&vendors=Dell&vendors=HP&vendors=Intel&vendors=Lenovo). Also, under the "Ubuntu Image" option, you can select pre-installed or downloaded from ubuntu.com to look at different pre-installed or self installable models.

[System76](https://system76.com/laptops), Dell, and HP all sell Ubuntu pre-installed on laptops (and I think you can special order dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu on any cheaper Dell models too but you have to purchase directly from Dell).

Also, you can't be sure that the installation will go without any problems. However, there is much less at stake if you aren't installing dual boot and you just want to install Ubuntu as the only OS. Typically, the worst case scenario is accidentally deleting Windows.

If you run into a problem, it's almost always fixable. Google search for the error or the problem and/or google the problem along with the term "askubuntu" to get better results.

Answer (score 3):

There ARE several reputable vendors selling high-quality pre-installed Ubuntu systems. Consider one of them. Otherwise....

- Buy from a reputable vendor with a reasonable return policy.
- Test the hardware with a LiveUSB. Pay close attention to Video card, GPU, and Wireless when testing -- a few component manufacturers do not provide Linux support.
- Most hardware IS compatible with Ubuntu - your experience was unusual. However specialty hardware (like Microsoft-branded hardware) is sometimes incompatible with Linux.

I've bought dozens of different models of laptops and desktops and servers over the paste decade - ALL of them have worked with Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I can only give my own recommendation. I have an HP Zbook G5. It runs Ubuntu like a dream. Once I installed the official NVIDIA driver, I’ve had no problems whatsoever.

Edit. It seems I can’t edit my credentials for this answer. While, it is certainly true, I do not recommend the Surface Book for a seamless Linux experience. The base unit (including the discrete graphics processor) cannot be reached without a controller whose driver Microsoft only wrote for Windows. Touch is still very finicky, even on more modern GUIs like GNOME 3. Also, the unit, in my experience, sometimes hangs on shutdown. If none of this is a problem, then the Surface Book is a fine Linux laptop. Just be sure to use a distro with a new-ish kernel (no older than 4.18 or so). Otherwise the keyboard and trackpad will not be recognized by the OS, and you will have problems with the WiFi driver.

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge.  Why do you need to dual-boot, when virtual machines are available?

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is free to use, even for commercial use, and works very well.  Other VM systems such as [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/) also exist.  Ubuntu is one of the major test platforms for VM systems, so you can be pretty confident that it will work.

If you want to do some hardcore number-crunching which needs to occupy the entire processor, or run some application/game which needs direct access to your graphics hardware to run effectively, then a VM may not be the best solution.  For general use though, and especially as a beginner trying to get familiar with a new OS, a VM is *exactly* what you want.  It's a low-risk, low-hassle way to run that new OS without having to change everything.

So everything you currently have running in Windows, you can keep it all.  No changes to disk partitioning, no reinstallation, no backups needed. If you want to run Linux, you can fire up a VM and run Linux.  If you want to run multiple different versions of Linux, you can set up as many VMs as you want (within limits of your storage space!).  You can even keep working in Windows whilst you simultaneously do other stuff in Linux, or even run multiple Linux VMs simultaneously.

I do this on a daily basis.  My laptop runs Windows 10, because that is our corporate environment.  For development though, I have two different Ubuntu VMs for developing two different sets of software (so that the two installations do not conflict).  I also have a VM running Windows 10 and a VM running Windows 7, for developing Windows software without all that installing/uninstalling clogging up my laptop's base setup, and to limit their access to the corporate network.  I will normally have two VMs running at the same time (one Windows, one Linux), as well as other applications and files open from the regular laptop Windows environment.  This does need a reasonable amount of RAM and processor cores, but anything above a netbook should be able to cope.

Comment: Are netbooks even still made? Modern phones have been more capable than the typical spec range of a netbook for at least half a decade. Frustratingly, there also about as big as netbooks these days, too.

Comment: @TylerH Yep, they're still out there.  Substantial crossover with tablets, of course, and there's the Chromebook range which are netbook hardware running Android.

Comment: @PeterMortensen A reasonable modern laptop is so far away from needing all those resources, it's basically immaterial.  Ubuntu can happily run with a single core and 1GB of RAM.  Your base Windows 10 gets a little slow with only 2GB left, but is happy with more.  If your laptop has at least 4GB of physical RAM and 2 cores, you're fine.

Comment: @PeterMortensen ... If you're doing hardcore number-crunching then you might need more, of course. My Ubuntu VM which does FPGA builds needs 4GB of RAM and 2 cores to itself, for instance.  My other Ubuntu VM doing C builds with GCC is fine with 1GB and 1 core though.  The Windows 10 host only usually has 1 core to itself, plus between 2GB and 4GB depending on VMs running.  In the OP's situation where they're wanting something just to get started, it's radically unlikely there would be any problem.